# Открытие разных Activity в зависимости от содержания EditText

Tags: android, activity, android-edittext

Такая проблема: я хочу ввести в EditText текст, и в зависимости от него у меня будут открываться разные Activity.
Например: ввожу в EditText слово машинка, и у меня открывается Activity с картинкой машинки, или ввожу в EditText слово самолёт, и у меня открывается Activity со словом самолёт. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Предоставьте ваш код, и мы вам поможем

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `TextWatcher`:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.toString().equals("машинка")) {
                Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
          }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edText);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = editText.getText().toString();
                Intent intent;
                switch (text){
                    case "машина":
                        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityA.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case "самолет":
                        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"не было введено машина или самолет", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                }


            }
        });


    }
}
```